# Diplomurkunde and Diplom (Diplomlehrer) in English?

Tags: job-search, degree

This might be off-topic but I thought I would try here since I know we have people who will know the answer.

I have received two documents from a prospective teacher. They seem to be German diplomas but I do not understand clearly what they really mean. The names of the diplomas are:

1. Diplomurkunde, and
2. Diplom (Diplomlehrer)

(1) translates (via Google) as Diploma Certificate. This is a bit confusing because I normally think of certificates as something and a diploma as something else (which requires more studying).

(2) translates as Graduate Teacher. This seems to be quite different from what I'm used to as a graduate teacher is something you are (or something you do) rather than something you've achieved.

Is there a more detailed explanation which would tie back to the UK or US educational system?

Comment: you should be able to create a new tag just by typing it in.  The academia faq says you should only need 150 rep to create a tag (this number varies by site).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pre-Bologna process, a German *Diplom* (which <strike>is no longer being awarded, and</strike> [see cbeleites's comment below] is mostly replaced now by a Master's degree) was generally the rough equivalent of a US Master's degree, attaining it is one of the requirements to start Doctorate studies.

Your applicant sent you two documents:

1. The *Diplomurkunde* is roughly the Master's diploma in the US. It is called a "certificate" (Urkunde) to distinguish it from the *Diplomzeugnisse* which also includes the transcript of grades. It is the one that one may consider framing and putting on the wall.
2. The *Diplomlehrer* tells you what subject the applicant received his "masters" in. In particular, he received it in *Lehrer*, which translates directly to <strike>Lecturer</strike> Teacher. Or, as we may say, it tells you that he received something like a Master's in education.

To clear up any doubts, though, you could just ask your applicant to ask the *Akademisches Auslandsamt* of the place where he received the degree to send a letter attesting to the equivalency of the degree. (That shouldn't be too hard, since now they should've converted to a Bachlor/Master system anyway.)

Comment: This letter of equivalency is called "Diploma Supplement", and the applicant can usually get it in the exam office of the university that granted the degree. It also gives translation instructions of the grades.

Comment: BTW: Some departments decided to continue the Diplom, e.g. engineering at TU Dresden (http://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/fakultaeten/fakultaet_maschinenwesen/studieninteressierte/diplomingenieur/index_html/document_view). The rule is that they have to offer Bachelor/Master courses, but are free to offer additional Diplom courses.

Comment: @cbeleites: thanks for the corrections! I completely wasn't aware that the Diplom system is still available.

Comment: "Lehrer" translates to "teacher".

Comment: @cbeleites and Willie Wong - The two diplom documents are separated by four years. Does this mean the candidate has the equivalent of two master degrees?

Comment: @earthling: beats me. Why don't you ask the candidate?

Comment: @A.Schulz fixed. Though I profess I am not exactly clear on the finer points of the difference. (I am not thinking of lecturer as the academic title, but as someone who gives lectures.)

Comment: @WillieWong It's a good question but he's German and doesn't understand UK/US academic systems.

Comment: @earthling: you can simply ask the candidate whether he holds two separate degrees. There's nothing much I can tell you based on the information you've given us. The Diploms just tell you a certain authority has given the candidate certain degree(s) on certain dates. If you need to know the details, I would [second cbeleites](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/9274/94) and tell you to ask the candidate for the Diplom supplement in English.

Comment: But if all you care about is whether the candidate has received "something like a masters degree in education", I think the conclusion is that "yes, he does". Does the fact that he may have two separate degrees matter?

Answer (score 5):

'Diplom' is the standard academic degree in Germany (slowly being replaced by a bachelor/master system). In the German system, it is roughly equivalent to a master degree. It usually takes about 5 years to complete. 
Teachers-to-be in Germany usually take a combination of two subjects. Their studies include courses on teaching/education as well.

Since schools are subject to special federal law, teachers usually end their studies with a state-controlled exam ("Staatsexamen").

Regarding the word "Diplomurkunde": The word simply denotes the piece of paper confirming that the person holds the respective degree. It is the one you want to see.
I'm not so sure about the other one, but from my own experience, I would guess that the "Diplomurkunde" simply has the applicants name, place of birth and a date one it, while the other document has a bit more information but basically grants the same degree.

Cf the article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplom

Comment: _It is the one you want to see_ — What?  People still use paper for this?

Comment: @JeffE: sure. And occasionally you even have to hand in certified copies of these pieces of paper...

Comment: @JeffE: Germany is _verrückt_ when it comes to paperwork. I was expected to show paperwork for a degree _I didn't even have_. (I don't have a master's.)

Comment: You better also have you high school dilpoma ready. Not to forget the Polizeiliches Führungszeugnis.

Comment: @aeismail: I know a university that required me to hand in several (I think in total ≈ 5) copies of the Diplom *they* gave me. Of course always with a copies of the Abitur, so they now have ≈ 6 copies of that as well (additional one for entering the university as student)...

Answer (score 2):

(answering the comment)

4 years separation would be enough to do the teaching program after the "normal" subject. And it would definitively not be the parts of one Diplom (Zeugnis + Urkunde), they have the same date.
And, by the way, till now I was always required to show/hand in both Urkunde and Zeugnis of my Diplom. As I understand it, the Urkunde certifies that I have the "title" of Diplom-chemist, the Zeugnis certifies the grades of the final exams, and possibly other legally relevant additional exams (the examn that allows me to handle chemicals according to the German laws).

I'm wondering a bit about the teaching Diplom - usually the teaching studies end with "Staatsexamen" (state exams, also includes one or two theses). But this can differ a lot depending on the state, and I don't know that much about the teaching studies. AFAIK, if you have a master/Diplom in some subject and then do the teaching studies for this subject, you can get the master/Diplom recognized as the first state exam. Otherwise, what you write sounds like 2 separate Diplome.

I guess it boils down to asking and getting the Diploma Supplements - AFAIK they explain what the Diplom is about.